# PHP: Download file from android browser default

Tags: php, android, browser, download

I have code download file such as:

```
$path = "../wap/file/{$row['file_name']}";
$filename = $row['file_name'];
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header('Content-Type: application/octetstream');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header("Content-Type: application/save");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$row['file_name']}\"");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
readfile($path);
```

When I download file on android by Opera, download successful. But if download file by browser default of android, download failed!